# Plesk, SMTP and sending e-mail from same domain

Tags: smtp, plesk

I have a server with Plesk installed.
On that I've created a domain, my-domain.com, and added and e-mail account noreply@my-domain.com with access to SMTP for sending e-mails.

With PHPMailer or Swift Mailer I am able to send via the SMTP account noreply@my-domain.com whenever the from address is outside the my-domain.com, for example info@my-second-domain.com.
Whenever I'm using an e-mail address that ends on @my-domain.com it fails.

I've tried to look in the /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog file, but it only stores the mails that doesn't fail.

Can someone help me figure out where the problems is?

Comment: I've activated the logger in Swift Mailer and got the following error message:


>> RCPT TO: <my-email@my-second-domain.com> 
<< 550 sorry, no mailbox here by that name. (#5.7.17) 
!! Expected response code 250/251/252 but got code "550", with message "550 sorry, no mailbox here by that name. (#5.7.17) "

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this:

Delete the related domain in the qmail file /var/qmail/control/virtualdomains
Then reload/restart qmail. Now it should work. 
More technical background at http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-93222.html

Answer (score 8):

Benjamin answer didn't work on my installation (Plesk 11.5), but I found another solution:
just turn off the mail service itself. It might not be the solution for everyone but it was for me (my domain's mx records pointing to another server, with some scripts sending emails here and there).

You can turn off the mail service fairly easily using Plesk GUI.

[image: Mail tab then Change Settings button]

Then uncheck

[image: Uncheck 'Activate mail on service on domain']

However, this won't turn it off for subdomains and secondary domains you might have. No problem, just log in with ssh and run this command:

> /usr/local/psa/bin/domain -u mydomain.example.com -mail_service false

And if one day you decide you want to turn it back on just replace false by true.

Comment: Your solution just saved my ass. Than you sir